# Keyboard misbehaves in Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard, osx-mountain-lion

My keyboard has screwed up big time. I was playing Team Fortress 2 and after I closed it out, my keyboard has adopted a weird behavior. Perhaps it is TF2's fault or perhaps I somehow accidentally entered some weird shortcut while playing. Previously, Mountain Lion never suggested alternate letters for the keys that I press (i.e. û, ü, ù, ú, and ū for pressing the u key). Sometimes arrow keys, tabs, and returns seem to be sent when I am not doing so as well as the cursor jumping around. I also can no longer hold a key to repeat it. I really do not want to reinstall Mountain Lion. Does anybody have any ideas as to what will fix this? I have looked in the System Preferences seemingly everywhere to no avail.

Comment: Lion and Mountain Lion have a feature that turns off key-repeat, replacing it with similar behaviour to what you describe. I suspect you've run afoul of this setting, which can be disabled.

Comment: I think `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` is what you are talking about. It does enable key repeat but (1) it worked before fiddling with this and (2) it still don't solve all the other problems.

Comment: That's why I commented and didn't answer outright. Good luck tracking this down. What happens with a different keyboard? Also, do you think you enabled a foreign keyboard map by accident?

Comment: I don't have another one at hand at the moment. :( EDIT: Sigh. I have to type very slowly. My computer just crashed from replying to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, it has to do with MagicPrefs. I changed some settings while playing TF2. I turned off "Tap to click" option in the "Point & Click" section of the Trackpad settings in the System Preferences (to enabled Taps options in MagicPrefs) **and** enabled and set both "One Finger Tap" settings in the "MacBook Trackpad" settings in MagicPrefs to "Left Click (Down+Up)". I noticed that it's only the first of the two that causes the problem. It seems to be sending the corresponding action at spontaneous times (when typing). For example, when I changed it to "Right Click (Down+Up)", a context menu frequently showed up. Changing the settings back to normal fixed this. This must be a bug with MagicPrefs and I may get around to submitting a bug report.